Joining on-prem clients to Active Directory in the cloud
Our company has a few Google Cloud VMs running windows server, our on prem machines connect to these VMs over a VPN. We don´t have physical servers, everything is in the cloud.
We are working to implement Active Directory. Currently, all our machines are standard to each employee (not joined to any AD domain), and thus we have very little control over them, we can not assing group policies and so on. We would like more control over these machines.
So far we have taken one of the VMs and raised it to domain controller. We have installed the nessesary server roles such as DNS and remote desktop services.
The problem here raises when we try to join one of our on prem machines to the domain.
When we hit the option in the client to join the domain and type the domain name, the credentials dialog window appears, we put in the name and password for the user hit enter, after a while an error occurs and it fails to join the domain.
I can't replicate the error at the moment but as soon as I can I will update it here.
Is there any tool in AD to see if the client is reaching the domain controller, if it is seeing the request, and so i can see the error it produces server-side?

Microsoft has documentation to debug domain controller join problems. Try this first before posting a question: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/active-directory/active-directory-domain-join-troubleshooting-guidance

I've run through that documentation already, gonna try to do it again though, maybe I misssed something...

If you have gone through that documentation, edit your question with the tests you performed and the results. Otherwise, we can only guess as you have not provided enough details to solve your problem.

You need to do or check the following:
Verify connectivity from on prem to your cloud hosted machines with the following commands (from on-prem machines):
Check the IP which the domain resolves:
nslookup <domain-hostname>

Verify listening port number (53,88,389)

telnet <domain-hostname> -p 389

Test-NetConnection <IP_address_of_the_DC> -Port 389

Depending on the outputs of the commands above, you may check either of the following

VPN Configuration Routes

Firewall Rules (for services or ports that are allowed) on both on-prem and on the cloud

DNS configuration of local network



Although your answer is helpful, the OP has not provided enough details to generate a correct answer. I recommend not posting general debugging tips to motivate the OP to improve their question first. Otherwise, the question and answer has limited value in the future.
